# SQLite 3 drops part of a string on INSERT if it represents a number

Tags: sqlite

If I try to insert a number as a string and number ends with ".0" SQLite drops this part.

For example, if I call this code in sqlite3 I got 1 as answer, not 1.0.

`CREATE TABLE test (val STRING NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('1.0');
SELECT * FROM test;`

If then I open the database in SQLiteman (a visual client) it's still 1.

It broke my code, so now I use replacement to _ before writing to DB but it's a crunch and I can't be sure that this behaviour won't break something else in the future.

**Can I somehow disable this behaviour? And why does it work such a strange way?**

My sqlite3 version is 3.20.1

Comment: Can you include a screen shot or text of the result of the select statement?

Comment: Here are a [screenshot](http://gameraccoon.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Screenshot-from-2017-11-07-10-00-29.png).

By the way, gilbdud's solution is worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRING` is not a meaningful data type in SQLite. What you're looking for is `TEXT`. See [Datatypes in SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (val TEXT NOT NULL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('1.0');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test;
1.0
```